# Cloud Spanner C++ ORM

Tags: c++, orm, google-cloud-spanner

Does Spanner have an ORM for C++ like Java? Cannot find any open source C++ ORM. Do people write actual SQL queries to interact with Spanner while coding in C++?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is an ORM for Java or C++.

When it comes to official ORM, only [Hibernate](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/use-hibernate), [Spring Data](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/adding-spring) and [Django](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/introducing-django-cloud-spanner-database) are supported.

So in this case, I think it would be best to create a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190851&template=0) for Google to consider implementing more options.